# How to achieve UI similar to Photos app with MonoTouch

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am looking for a UI similar to the Photos app.  The first screen would be a list of "Albums" (UITableView), when clicking on the album, you would be brought to a UI filled with thumbnails of which you can touch one of them and then swipe back and forth through them.  Again, identical functionality to the Photos app.  I'd prefer to use MonoTouch.Dialog as much as possible.

The part that I am having the most difficultly figuring out is the UI will with the thumbnails.  I suppose once you touched an image, you'd be in UIScrollView but one that has navigation to bring you back to the UI with all the thumbnails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using iOS 6, I would look into the UICollectionView. It is designed to be used in scenarios just like you are describing.

I would recommend watching  [WWDC sessions 205 and 219](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/)

There is an open source solution on GitHub that supports iOS 4.3+ if you are still looking for options. I haven't actually used it, but it looks like it works in a similar way to UICollectionView. I am not sure if there is a MonoTouch port or wrapper, but it shouldn't be too hard to do.

[PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView)

Good Luck!